# beagle bone board is printing continuously 'c' on uart

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

My beaglebone black is continuously printing 'c' on the serial port.

Can anyone help me understanding what is wrong with it. Why it is not booting with emmc, and how to flash the emmc with new image.

Answer (score 1):

Its from the AM335x's ROM code, which can't find a boot device. You should put an image on an SD card and then load it onto the EMMC like this:

-boot up
-ssh to the device or use the debug terminal
-sudo nano /boot/uEnv.txt
-uncomment this:  (remove the hashtag)

```
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

-save (ctrl+x and y)
-shut down the unit and unplug power
-power on while holding the S2 button
-it will now flash the device